# Unable to update my table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[This is how my table from db currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HFoc.png)

```
    $itemquant=$_GET["itemquant"];
    $itemprice=$_GET["itemprice"];
    $v_date=$_GET["date2"];
    $newdatestring=$_GET["newdate2"];

    $val2=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT TransactionID FROM `transaction` WHERE `TransactionDate`='$v_date'");
    while($row12 = mysqli_fetch_array($val2))
    { 
        $sql=("UPDATE transaction SET  ItemQuantity='$itemquant',ItemPrice='$itemprice' WHERE `transaction`.`TransactionID` = '$row12[0]'");
        $val=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if(!$val)
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    $val=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$val)
        die(mysqli_error($conn));
        echo ("Table updated successfully");
```

Now this is my code to update the field, what this code does is it changes all of the fields with the same value even if i change the value i.e quantity/ price of only one row.

I am able to add new rows to it but somehow the update just wont work and my brain seems to tired that i had to reach for help

Comment: first of all echo $sql; and copy that query and paste that query in phpmyadmin sql page  and check what happen.

Comment: You execute query twice `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

Comment: @Saty yes you are right.

Comment: And add `MYSQLI_NUM` to `mysqli_fetch_array($val2,MYSQLI_NUM);` to get numeric array

Answer (score 0):

Just check weather you are getting any value at the variable

```
$row12[0]
```

If not try

```
$row12['TransactionID']
```

am not considering anything other, just check this and please search google for this kind of doubts please.